# Rule based symbology rendering order with expression

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to create a map of origins and destinations as a bubble map.

[image]

As you can see on the above image (green: origins, red: destinations). I have applied rule based symbology with expression on symbol size in the **same layer**. However, some red green bubble information being lost when I try to do that due to rendering order. I want to always render the bubble with bigger value so that they will both appear on the map. Is there a way to do that with rule based symbology? If not what is the proper way to do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are those points of origin/destination in one layer or they are two different?

Comment: they are in one layer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In rule based symbology, rules are applied in order.

You can draw the `origin` first, then the `destination`, and, again, re-draw the `origin` only if it is smaller than the `destination` (copy/paste the 1st rule and apply a condition)

[image]

Comment: I was easier than I though ... you are genius

Comment: it is far from perfect though, because any change to the 1st rule must be replicated to the last rule

Comment: Yes, but still this is the first working solution till now

Comment: To limit duplication I would also filter the first rule with origin >= destination so that each feature is only drawn once.

Comment: "Any change to the 1st rule must be replicated to the last rule": a workaround could be to use (custom) variables for style and filter settings that are used bot an 1st an last rule

Comment: You can set a size of your circles via `Size > Edit ...` using this expression `scale_linear("Field",minimum("Field"),maximum("Field"),1,10)`